# Real Hypersurfaces In Complex Manifolds

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-manifolds

I have a problem:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

=================

I don't understand (2.12) and (2.13) :( How to prove that
$$PF=\sum_{\min(k,l) \le 1}F_{kl}+G_{11}\left \langle z,z \right \rangle +\left ( G_{10}+G_{01} \right )\left \langle z,z \right \rangle^2+G_{00}\left \langle z,z \right \rangle^3$$

(**Source**: Real Hypersurfaces In Complex Manifolds By S.S.Chern and J.K.Moser)

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!